# What does the "Couldn't compile connection:" error mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compiler-errors, storyboard

I'm getting the following error from Xcode:

```
Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x401538380
<IBProxyObject: 0x40154a260> => categoryPicker => <IBUIPickerView: 0x4016de1e0>>
```

I've narrowed this down to a single outlet connection in storyboard.  My code (about 30 views with lots of other connections) compiles and runs fine until I add a connection from a UIPicker to the view's categoryPicker property.  The picker itself also works fine, I just can't reload it without getting this connection to work:

```
@interface FiltersTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    FilterTableViewController *filterView;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) FilterTableViewController *filterView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;

- (void)configureCell:(FilterTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)performFetch;

@end
```

The UIPickerView is in a UITableViewCell.  Here's an image of the storyboard, the connection from "categoryPicker" to "FiltersTableViewController" causes the error:
[image]

Thanks for any ideas, or suggestions on how to debug it!

EDIT:
I removed the connection and added one line to numberOfComponentsInPickerView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    categoryPicker = pickerView;

    return 1;
```

}

This now works!, but I'd like to understand why the connection won't work and what that error message means.  Right now this seems like a kludge to me since I use IB connections everywhere else to get object references.

EDIT 2:
Connecting a prototype cell generates this error: Illegal Configuration: Connection "Cell" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.  Not sure if this is new in Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Seems like the problem is, categoryPicker is "weak" and FilterTableViewController is "strong". Try to make categoryPicker strong as well and check if that works

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried it, but it doesn't change anything.  (I'm under the impression that IBOutlets should be weak...I get that from here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5773/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2).

Comment: Yes thats technically right, sorry my bad! As I just read that in Apple documentation too!

Comment: so you just want to set your ViewController as a delegate of categoryPicker...am I right? have you tried categoryPicker.delegate = self; ?

Comment: The ViewController is already a delegate, and that part works.  The problem is categoryPicker is nil without the connection from IB, and I can't call reloadAllComponents on it.  I actually did just get something to work, but it seems like a kludge.  I'll add it to the question in a sec...

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The problem is that this is a prototype cell. It is meaningless to have an outlet to something in it, because it isn't a real cell: it's a model for what might be dozens or hundreds of cells, and which one would the outlet point to in that case?

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense now, the other places I use connections for this kind of thing use static cells.

Comment: matt, thanks for the answer. I'm stuck now. how do i address these objects like label button etc without a outlet?

Comment: Use tags and call `viewWithTag:`, or subclass UITableViewCell so that each _cell_ has an outlet pointing to its _own_ button.

Comment: @carbonr Also, you can save a reference from one of the delegate methods, like I did for categoryPicker above.  Of course this only worked for me because there's only one picker instance.

Comment: I am able to create the connections on prototype cell without any problem? So is that still valid?

Comment: @theiOSguy I think it is as I just ran into this problem.

Comment: Well you could use the tag of the button to recognize the cell. An outlet from a cell prototype should be allowed and would be possible.

Answer (score 24):

**SWIFT 2**

I was creating a *popover segue* and I was getting the same error.

What I did was follow @matt's answer by **not putting it on a cell**, which is logical now that he explained it!

Instead, I put the **TableView as the anchor** and it worked fine.

Hope that helps those in the future.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, i had this problem on swift 2 and i didn't know why

Comment: Glad it helped! @darkndream

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski I just added a popover segue + TableView as an Anchor in the Storyboard as explained above.

Comment: Note that you can then change the anchor to point to the correct cell during prepareforSegue to the actual cell.  (pass cell as sender in performSegue; then segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView  = (UIView *) sender