# iOS: Couldn't compile connection: UIImageView in Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, cell

I am parsing a XML-File with NSXMLParser. The number of cells depends on how many entries the XML-File has. This all works fine.

Now I added an UIImageView to my Prototype Cell, in which I'd like to load my URL (declared in the XML-File).

**My Storyboard Error: Couldn't compile connection..**

I know it's due to the Prototype Cell. But how can I add a UIImageView to all Cells, where different images from XML can be displayed?

EDIT:

Heres my Code, but this is not important.. every time I connect the UIImageView in Interface Builder, the error shows up..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"productCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

XMLProductView *listedProduct = [appDelegate.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

/*
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:operation];
*/

NSString *imageURL = listedProduct.image;

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

[imageView setImage:image];

cell.textLabel.text = listedProduct.name;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

}

Comment: I added my Code but I don't think this causes the error.

Comment: have you added your imageView to cell?

Comment: Yes, and connected. But when I disconnect it, the error disappears. I can do what I want, the Image doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your imageView is an outlet? It should not be wired to a Prototype cell. You can add the imageView in program:

```
 [cell addSubview:imageView];
```

or create the imageView in storyboard and get it through:

```
 [cell viewWithTag:theTagOfImageView];
```

Edit 2

I think it is really what you need. Good luck!

[LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)

Comment: thank you lu for your answer. I tried both but nothing works.. I checked some posts here on SO and found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693595/cant-compile-connection-ios5. But I am not sure if it works.

Comment: @AlexisW I think it should work. As i do it this way without problem. plz check more carefully, and put the code which you have tried:)

Comment: okay lu, I tried this code: `UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];` and `imageView2.image = image;`. But nothing works .___.''

Comment: @AlexisW plz put some code in your answer and tell me what's "nothing works"?

Comment: Hi lu, code is in there? my problem: the image does not get shown.

Comment: @AlexisW ok, no "Couldn't compile connection.." right? Now, you should do something when your image is downloaded. Detail plz check the LazyTableImage sample code. I will put the download link in my answer.

Comment: the code is quite another way than I'd like to solve this problem. Everything works fine expect this imageview. I cannot change my whole code for this.

Comment: @AlexisW The principle is similar

Comment: hey lu, I found the error: as shown in your link and I don't need to set an UIImageView to the prototype cell. for me it's made with `cell.imageView.image = image;` without an out-pointing reference. thank you :)