# Getting a "Couldn't compile connection" when creating a UIView connection in storyboards

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I have a `TableView` controller and on top of this I just drag a `UIView` and populated with 3 buttons. After I create a IBOutlet to this view, my app won't run anymore and it gives me this error:

```
Main.storyboard: Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x7fa2d2c28d70  <IBProxyObject: 0x7fa2d2c27ec0> => shareView => <IBUIView: 0x7fa2d2cf74d0>>
```

What am I doing wrong ? What can I do get rid of this error ?

edit: When I try to drag from the Connections Inspector to the view I realised that his selecting the cell of the tableview not the my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving a lot of detail, but it might be similar to this question:

[What does the "Couldn't compile connection:" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236621/what-does-the-couldnt-compile-connection-error-mean)

**Edit:** I saw your edit, so it's probably the same as that one.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is because of the `UITableViewController`. When you use a `UITableViewController` you should only use it as a TableView and nothing additional. But I recommend to use instead a `UITableView` so you can resize it and also you can easy add `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag a view into a table view, it becomes the table's header view. Instead of making an outlet to it, you can get a pointer to it in code with ,

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
```

You should import your custom class (if you have one for this view), and cast the result to that, so you can access it's properties.

Comment: Are you sure ? I changed the colour of tableHeaderView but I didn't do nothing to my view.

Comment: @vBx, Yeah I'm sure. I just tested again on a new project (and setting the color worked for me). Are you sure you dragged this view into the table view, or did you drag it onto the cell? Which is it a subview of? –