# "The constraint outlet from the TableViewController to the NSLayoutConstraint is invalid." error

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to create an `@IBOutlet` to modify a constraint of an `UILabel` that is inside of an `UITableViewCell` but I am getting the following error:

> The constraint outlet from the CustomTableViewController to the NSLayoutConstraint is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

I guess from the error that it is because it is being repeated each time in each row but I am not able to solve this.

I have searched a lot and related errors did not solve anything to me because most of them suggest if I have more than one `@IBOutlet` to the same constraint. I have checked it but I do not have it duplicated (of course it is going to be more than one constraint when rows are more than 1).

I do not think it could be relevant for this issue but I am using Swift 3.0.

How can I solve this? I am totally stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you work with .XIb then you can access that constrain outlet otherwise its not access

Comment: You have to creat the outlet of that label within the TableViewCell class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9236869/341994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a `UITableViewCell` subclass. In the declaration, declare an outlet property whose value is an `NSLayoutConstraint`. In the storyboard, select the prototype cell and set its class to be your subclass. Draw the outlet between the cell and the constraint. In your `cellForRowAt` implementation, cast the dequeued cell to your subclass. Now you can refer to the constraint property.

Comment: You are very welcome. Your question was very well asked: you explored the matter thoroughly and had an excellent grasp of the problem before formulating the question.