# iOS Custom UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use UITableView with custom style I have got a red warning in the storyboard (uncategorized compilation failed).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    codeLabel.text = [[courseMURArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"courseCode"];
    nameLabel.text = [[courseMURArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"courseName"];
    houreLabel.text = @"3";
    priceLabel.text = @"0.000";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: If you answer your own question, please add an answer in the answers area.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"YourCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init]; //or some other init, don't have a Mac nearby, don't remember it by heart
    }

    self.codeLabel.text = [[courseMURArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"courseCode"];
    self.nameLabel.text = [[courseMURArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"courseName"];
    self.houreLabel.text = @"3";
    self.priceLabel.text = @"0.000";

    [cell addSubview:self.codeLabel];
    [cell addSubview:self.nameLabel];
    [cell addSubview:self.houreLabel];
    [cell addSubview:self.priceLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but I am guessing that your app is failing to build.  Look below for a possible solution to your problem and some steps to help you find the issue.

[Xcode 4.2 Compilation Failed with prototype cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7042279/558933)